# "Translating" NoSQL API to Azure Synapse - query works in Cosmos DB but not in Synapse?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following query I can successfully run in Azure Cosmos DB:

```
SELECT 
c.TrfId
, c.NewData[0]["value"] AS "NodeID"
, c.NewData[1]["value"] AS "FilePath"

FROM c
WHERE c.NewData <> null
```

However, when I move the query to Synapse, it keeps giving me this error: **Incorrect syntax near '"value"'**, which is caused by the 2 NewData columns (it works if I just get the entire NewData column).

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(​PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
                CONNECTION = 'Account=account;Database=database',
                OBJECT = 'object',
                SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'servercred'
) WITH (

[TrfId] varchar(256)
, [NewData][0]["value"] varchar(max) AS "ECMNodeID"
, [NewData][1]["value"] varchar(256) AS "ECMFilePath"

) AS [data]

WHERE [NewData] is not null    
GO
```

Can someone point out exactly what I'm doing wrong here? Or is what I'm doing won't translate to Synapse due to technical limitations, etc.? I tried removing the aliases but it doesn't work either. Below is a sample of the data:

```
{
    "TrfId": "10_000436",
    "NewData": [
        {
            "key": "ECM ID",
            "value": "233462908"
        },
        {
            "key": "ECM file path",
            "value": "2022-Feb-21.pdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't expect to use the same SQL syntax in Azure Cosmos DB and in Azure Synapse SQL Serverless. The query engines are completely different, and different syntaxes are enforced. Azure Synapse SQL Serverless uses T-SQL language while Cosmos DB uses a subset of ANSI SQL. With Synapse Link and Azure Synapse SQL Serverless you can even do joins between collections, what is not supported in Cosmos DB SQL language.

With that said, your query is wrong. Please check our documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-cosmos-db-analytical-store?toc=%2Fazure%2Fcosmos-db%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fcosmos-db%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&tabs=openrowset-key#query-nested-objects

If you have any difficulty with our documentation, that explains how to query Cosmos DB data with SQL Serverless, please reach out to us: cosmosdbsynapselink@microsoft.com

Tks

Comment: I tried the sample syntax in the linked KB however still ran across an error:

I tried the sample syntax in the linked KB however I'm still getting an error though:

    `, [ECMNodeID] varchar(max) '$.NewData.key'`

    `, [ECMFilePath] varchar(max) '$.NewData.value'`

I remember the "value" word being a reserved word, how do I specify it in the query in this case?

`Error handling external file: 'Cannot read column [NewData.key]. Accessing a column with a multi-element ancestor, such as LIST or MAP, is not supported. Try using a higher level column instead, such as [NewData]'.`

Comment: You are probably not using the correct WITH clause to format the data. Please email us with all details of your project: cosmosdbsynapselink@microsoft.com